# Condition that deletes rows older than 30 days

Tags: database

How can I query a condition that deletes the rows with column Date older than the last 30 days in DBTNG format?

I have tried this, but it's wrong.

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$connection->delete('my_table')
    ->condition('Date', now() . ' - INTERVAL 30 day', '>');
$connection->execute();
```

[image: Screenshot of table with nid and Date columns]

Comment: Is it a created date? you try using EntityTypeManager to query the condition, then loop and delete them one by one. I would do it using a batch approach.

Comment: PHP’s now() function (a deprecated alias for time()), which that code calls,   returns the current Unix timestamp. You can’t  subtract “INTERVAL 30 day” from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the field Date is type date and has values with the following format: Y-m-d (2023-04-04).

```
// Returns a timestamp equivalent to: 2023-07-01 17:20:53 UTC (today is 2023-07-31)
$range = strtotime('now -30 days'); 

// Converts the previous timestamp to Y-m-d format
$rangeTimestamp = date('Y-m-d', $range); 

// Stores the database service into a variable
$connection = \Drupal::database();
        
// Query that retrieves rows with column Date (Y-m-d) with a value older than specific range. 
$query =  $connection->delete('my_table')
          ->condition('Date', $rangeTimestamp, '<=')
          ->execute();

// If Date is greater or equal '>=', it's inside the range of 30 days.
// If Date is lower or equal '<=', it's outside the range, and is older than 30 days.
```

Comment: Actually, `$range` contains a timestamp and `$rangeTimestamp` contains a date string. The first variable should be really named `$rangeTimestamp`, and the second variable should be named `$range`. Actually, they are not ranges, so their names should not contain *range*.